# Are there any Hardware RAID Cards with Batteries that will work in a Mac Pro 3,1?

Tags: mac-pro, hardware-recommendation, raid, sata

I'm looking to install Proxmox on my MacPro3,1 and it's suggested that if you plan to use the system for 5 years that you install a Hardware RAID card with a battery in it, so that if the power goes out your "last writes" will be written before the machine runs out of juice.

Are there any Hardware RAID cards I can use in this machine? Also, how does one know when the battery on the card is dying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the 3,1 is essentially an unsupported machine [sadly] I'd go for a second-hand Apple card from eBay etc, to save any possible compatibility issues with a 3rd party new card that may never have been designed with the 08 Mac Pro in mind.

The official Mac Pro RAID cards themselves come in 2 flavours, pre & post 2009

Unless it's a refurb, I would also change the battery, new ones are still available.

UK prices, old RAID card for an Early 2008, approx £200, new battery £50

See [Mac Pro (Mid 2012 and earlier): Frequently Asked Questions about the Mac Pro RAID Card and Xserve RAID Card](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201160)

Comment: Note that the O/S will notify you when the battery is dying and it is not a catastrophe as the RAID config is written to each drive in the RAID container and is easily recoverable.

Comment: Good point, +1 ... I just thought better safe than sorry on a potentially 6-year-old device